# Seaborn Bar Plot Ordering

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a pandas dataframe that has two columns.

I need the plot ordered by the "Count" Column.

```
dicti=({'37':99943,'25':47228,'36':16933,'40':14996,'35':11791,'34':8030,'24' : 6319 ,'2'  :5055 ,'39' :4758 ,'38' :4611  })
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(list(dicti.iteritems()))
pd_df.columns =["Dim","Count"]
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = sns.barplot(x="Dim", y= "Count",data=pd_df )
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda x, loc: "
{:,}".format(int(x))))
ax.set(xlabel="Dim", ylabel='Count')
for item in ax.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(90)
for i, v in enumerate(pd_df["Count"].iteritems()):        
    ax.text(i ,v[1], "{:,}".format(v[1]), color='m', va ='bottom', 
    rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Right now the plot is getting ordered by the "Dim" column, I need it ordered by the "Count" column,How can I do this?[image]

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `barplot`? It takes a parameter called `order`. So you could sort by your `Count` column, and pass the resulting `Dim` values to that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have to sort your dataframe in desired way and the reindex it to make new ascending / descending index. After that you may plot bar graph with index as x values. Then set set labels by Dim column of your dataframe:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dicti=({'37':99943,'25':47228,'36':16933,'40':14996,'35':11791,'34':8030,'24' : 6319 ,'2'  :5055 ,'39' :4758 ,'38' :4611  })
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(list(dicti.items()))
pd_df.columns =["Dim","Count"]
print (pd_df)
# sort df by Count column
pd_df = pd_df.sort_values(['Count']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (pd_df)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
# plot barh chart with index as x values
ax = sns.barplot(pd_df.index, pd_df.Count)
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda x, loc: "{:,}".format(int(x))))
ax.set(xlabel="Dim", ylabel='Count')
# add proper Dim values as x labels
ax.set_xticklabels(pd_df.Dim)
for item in ax.get_xticklabels(): item.set_rotation(90)
for i, v in enumerate(pd_df["Count"].iteritems()):        
    ax.text(i ,v[1], "{:,}".format(v[1]), color='m', va ='bottom', rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Do I understand it correctly -- even if I have sorted dataframe I have to first create it using indices as labels to make sure sns does not sort bars alphabetically based on label names (and there is no way to pass, for example, `sorted = False`, to avoid that) ?

Answer (score 58):

you can use the order parameter for this.

```
sns.barplot(x='Id', y="Speed", data=df, order=result['Id'])
```

Credits to Wayne.

See the rest of his [code](https://gist.github.com/fomightez/bb5a9c727d93d1508187677b4d74d7c1).

This link is still working for me. But, for the sake of convenience, I'm pasting the author's code here.

```
result = df.groupby(["Id"])['Speed'].aggregate(np.median).reset_index().sort_values('Speed')
sns.barplot(x='Id', y="Speed", data=df, order=result['Id'])
plt.show()
```

df

```
   Id  Speed
0   1     30
1   1     35
2   1     31
3   2     20
4   2     25
```

result

```
   Id   Speed
1   2   22.5
0   1   31.0
2   3   80.0
```

Comment: but is it possible to sort by estimated value: `sns.barplot(x='Id', y="Speed", data=df, estimator=np.mean, order=?)`

Comment: There is likely a better way, but this works:    `grp_order = df.groupby('Id').Speed.agg('mean').sort_values().index` and then `sns.barplot(x='Id', y="Speed", data=df, estimator=np.mean, order=grp_order)`

Comment: I can't get this to work and the link doesn't show anything related to your solution. What is `result` supposed to be or return? A dict returning an int? That gives me an error

Comment: Would be better if you showed how `result` was evaluated. As it stands, you just present a one-liner which does not work.

Answer (score 12):

Prepare the data frame such that it is ordered by the column that you want.

Now pass that as a parameter to function.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dicti=({'37': 99943,'25': 47228,'36': 16933,'40': 14996,'35': 11791,'34': 8030,'24': 6319 ,'2': 5055 ,'39': 4758 ,'38' :4611})
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(list(dicti.items()))
pd_df.columns =["Dim", "Count"]

# Here the dataframe is already sorted if not use the below line
# pd_df = pd_df.sort_values('Count').reset_index()
# or 
# pd_df = pd_df.sort_values('Count',ascending=False).reset_index()

sns.barplot(x='Dim', y='Count', data=pd_df, order=pd_df['Dim'])`
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

To make a specific order, I recommend to create a list and then order by it:

```
order_list = ['first', 'second', 'third']
sns.barplot(x=df['x'], y=df['y'], order=order_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this. There is no need to sort the dataframe or create extra lists.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dicti=({'34':8030,'37':99943,'38':4611,'25':47228,'39':4758,'36':16933,'2':5055,'40':14996,'24':6319,'35':11791})
pd_df = pd.DataFrame(list(dicti.items()))
pd_df.columns =["Dim","Count"]
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
ax = sns.barplot(x="Dim", y= "Count",data=pd_df, order=pd_df.sort_values(by=['Count'], ascending=False).set_index('Dim').index)
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(plt.FuncFormatter(lambda x, loc: "{:,}".format(int(x))))
ax.set(xlabel="Dim", ylabel='Count')
for item in ax.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(90)
#for i, v in enumerate(pd_df["Count"].iteritems()):        
#    ax.text(i ,v[1], "{:,}".format(v[1]), color='m', va ='bottom', 
#    rotation=45)
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: output]

Note: You may notice that there are 3 lines of code that were turned to comments. This is because `@Tronald Dump` asked about the Seaborn Bar Plot functionality specifically, but there was code to display custom magenta labels that doesn't account for the usage of the optional "order" parameter of the seaborn.barplot function. Therefore, this serves as a valid answer for the OP, but specially for future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code

```
import seaborn as sns

iris = sns.load_dataset("iris")
order = iris.groupby(["species"])["sepal_width"].mean().sort_values().index

sns.barplot(x="species", y="sepal_width", data=iris, order=order)
```

[image]

You specify `ascending=False` if you want to sort them from biggest to smallest.

```
order = iris.groupby(["species"])["sepal_width"].mean().sort_values(ascending=False).index
```

Comment: This is great for cases where you don't want to sort on the absolute values, but instead on some statistic like the mean. Super useful!