# Ascending order of bars in seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

I have the following dataframe

```
   Class    Age Percentage
0   2004    3   43.491170
1   2004    2   29.616607
2   2004    4   13.838925
3   2004    6   10.049712
4   2004    5   2.637445
5   2004    1   0.366142
6   2005    2   51.267369
7   2005    3   19.589268
8   2005    6   13.730432
9   2005    4   11.155305
10  2005    5   3.343524
11  2005    1   0.913590
12  2005    9   0.000511
```

I would like to make a bar plot using seaborn where in the y-axis is the 'Percentage', in the x-axis is the 'Class' and label them using the 'Age' column. I would also like to arrange the bars in descending order, i.e. from the bigger to the smaller bar.

In order to do that I thought of the following: I will change the `hue_order` parameter based on the order of the 'Percentage' variable. For example, if I sort the 'Percentage' column in descending order for the `Class == 2004`, then the `hue_order = [3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 1]`.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

def hue_order():
    for cls in dataset.Class.unique():
        temp_df = dataset[dataset['Class'] == cls]
        order = temp_df.sort_values('Percentage', ascending = False)['Age']  
    return order

sns.barplot(x="Class", y="Percentage", hue = 'Age', 
                 hue_order= hue_order(),  
                 data=dataset)
plt.show()
```

However, the bars are in descending order only for the `Class == 2005`. Any help?

**In my question, I am using the `hue` parameter, thus, it is not a duplicate as proposed.**

[image: Result]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seaborn Bar Plot Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770507/seaborn-bar-plot-ordering)

Comment: @DavidG I am also using the hue parameter. Just sayin'.

Comment: @DavidG Have you actually read my question or just google something similar?

Comment: In `hue_order` you are looping over each class, but you overwrite `order` on each loop and finally return `order`at the end. So you will only get the `order` for the final `Class`

Comment: @KPLauritzen that's quite obvious. Can you propose me a solution to that?

Comment: @DimKoim not really. I'm not sure seaborn can do what you want. You might need to go to matplotlib directly.

Comment: Why down vote guys? What's the problem? Can a moderator help me to identify the problem?

Comment: I guess the problem with this question is that the real problem is somewhat hidden. Since you do not stick to [ask] here, clearly stating in how far this problem is not solved by other answers on this site, the first impression one gets here is that this should be duplicate. Next, the code you show contains an obvious error, so one might be tempted to think that this is just about getting a loop straight. Only after spending a lot of thoughts about this the actual problem becomes apparent, which seems to be that you want to use *different* hue orders for each x value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The seaborn `hue` parameter adds another dimension to the plot. The `hue_order` determines in which order this dimension is handled. However you cannot split that order. This means you may well change the order such that `Age == 2` is in the third place in the plot. But you cannot change it partially, such that in some part it is in the first and in some other it'll be in the third place.

In order to achieve what is desired here, namely to use different orders of the auxilary dimensions within the same axes, you need to handle this manually.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Class" : [2004]*6+[2005]*7,
                   "Age" : [3,2,4,6,5,1,2,3,6,4,5,1,9],
                   "Percentage" : [50,40,30,20,10,30,20,35,40,50,45,30,15]})

def sortedgroupedbar(ax, x,y, groupby, data=None, width=0.8, **kwargs):
    order = np.zeros(len(data))
    df = data.copy()
    for xi in np.unique(df[x].values):
        group = data[df[x] == xi]
        a = group[y].values
        b = sorted(np.arange(len(a)),key=lambda x:a[x],reverse=True)
        c = sorted(np.arange(len(a)),key=lambda x:b[x])
        order[data[x] == xi] = c   
    df["order"] = order
    u, df["ind"] = np.unique(df[x].values, return_inverse=True)
    step = width/len(np.unique(df[groupby].values))
    for xi,grp in df.groupby(groupby):
        ax.bar(grp["ind"]-width/2.+grp["order"]*step+step/2.,
               grp[y],width=step, label=xi, **kwargs)
    ax.legend(title=groupby)
    ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(u)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(u)
    ax.set_xlabel(x)
    ax.set_ylabel(y)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()    
sortedgroupedbar(ax, x="Class",y="Percentage", groupby="Age", data=df)
plt.show()
```

[image]