# Barplot sorting in Seaborn Plot

Tags: python, sorting, seaborn

I am trying to use a barplot with the seaborn library and cannot get my plot to sort by the highest value of the Y axis ("upspw"). What am I doing wrong?

```
attribute2_count=sns.barplot(x="attribute_2", y="upspw", data=df.sort_values("upspw"), palette="spring")
```

[Barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpnIZ.png)

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal working example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770507/seaborn-bar-plot-ordering

Comment: I couldn't get my bar plot to show up in my original question but if you do click on the link where it says Barplot, that should show the plot I have currently have.  y-axis is the "upspw" column and x-axis is the "attributes_2" column.